# Poor performance on Grails 3.2.9 application startup

Tags: java, grails, spring-boot

Recently I've been doing an update of an application from Grails 2.5.5 to Grails 3.2.9.

An application is serving ~3K RPM.

The issue I currently have is a poor performance after application startup. Our normal release process works in the following way (assuming 2 nodes setup):

1. 2 nodes with service are running.
2. Turn off the first node.
3. Release new version on the first node.
4. Service on the first node register itself in Eureka and start consuming requests.

(repeat same on second nodes)

Problems are starting to appear on the 4th step. The application responds quite slowly and timing is really inconsistent - some responses are in an expected time range, but some are really off normal.

Sample logs:

```
2017-09-01 08:03:38,594 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-72][][]- END controller=98ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:38,911 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-101][][]- END controller=134ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:38,948 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-56][][]- END  controller=211ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:39,156 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-82][][]- END  controller=95ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:39,124 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-111][][]- END controller=98ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:39,184 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-110][][]- END controller=4099ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:39,399 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-46][][]- END controller=24ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:39,428 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-43][][]- END  controller=191ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:39,744 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-83][][]- END  controller=117ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:40,335 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-56][][]- END  controller=483ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:45,595 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-110][][]- END controller=5623ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:45,618 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-83][][]- END  controller=5274ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:45,629 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-144][][]- END controller=2007ms
 2017-09-01 08:03:45,671 INFO [request][http-nio-12345-exec-119][][]- END  controller=4591ms
```

As you can see from it - few requests went below 100ms and some - more than 5 seconds.

My assumption is that’s happening due to slow warm up of Grails 3 application and lazy class loading.

Things I've already done:

1. `grais.gorm.autowire = false`
2. `grais.gorm.reactor.events = false`
3. Delay registration of service in Eureka for 30 seconds (to wait while applications is fully loaded)

The next thing which comes to my mind is to compile the project with `@CompileStatic` annotation.

Comment: Without profiling data, I don't think anyone can help you